# Progressing time in child process in mocha test

Tags: node.js, cron, mocha.js, sinon

I am using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to schedule a task to be executed once a day, and I want to test this in mocha.

I am using child_process.spawn to run the script, and I need to progress the internal clock of the created child. This is what i have so far:

```
it.only('Should run the script every 24 hours and trigger an event',function(done){
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(),
           path = process.cwd() + '/cronjob/',
           env = Object.create(process.env);

    env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
    var cronjob = child.spawn('node', ['index.js'], {
            cwd: path,
            env: env
     });
    cronjob.stdout.on('data',function(data){
          console.log(data);
          if (data.toString().trim() === 'Script ran successfully'){
               cronjob.kill('SIGINT');
               done();
          }
     });
     cronjob.stderr.on('data',function(data){
          done(new Error(data.toString()));
      });
      clock.tick(24*60*60*1000);
}
```

This only progresses time in the mocha test instance not in the index.js.
Is there any way i can pass the sinon timer to the child process?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will be at all useful, but I've done something similar using Node's `vm`. Here's a VERY simplified version of what I've done in the past.

Sample `index.js`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('ok');
}, 24*60*60*1000);
```

Sample `index.spec.js`

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var vm = require('vm');
var fs = require('fs');

describe('sample', function() {
  it('Should detect if script runs 24 hours later',function(){
    var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    var script = fs.readFileSync(require.resolve('../index.js'));
    sinon.stub(console, 'log');

    var result = vm.runInThisContext(script);
    clock.tick(24*60*60*1000);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(console.log);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(console.log, 'ok');

    console.log.restore();
  });
});
```

Sample output:

```
  sample
    ✓ Should run the script every 24 hours and trigger an event


  1 passing (19ms)
```

In the above sample code I accomplish the following:

1. setup Sinon's fake timers
2. stub `console.log()` so I can make assertions later
3. execute the sample `index.js` in `vm` using the current context, but isolated from the local scope (index.js calls `console.log()` 24 hours later)
4. time travel 24 hours using Sinon's fake timers
5. make assertions on calls to `console.log()`
6. restore `console.log()` (so Mocha reporters don't get cranky)

Since I don't know what's going on in your `index.js` it's hard to say if a solution like the one I've outlined above could be helpful, but I hope it is.